# Why can't I directly assign document.getElementById to a different function?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to define a function g() that is like document.getElementById. The following works just fine:

```
var g = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};
```

But why doesn't this more direct code work?

```
var g = document.getElementById;
```

Comment: Which browser? It works on Google Chrome.

Comment: Hmm. On Chrome for me window.onload = function(){
   var g = document.getElementById;
   g("testdiv").innerHTML = "it works!";
   
  } doesn't work, but window.onload = function(){
   var g = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};
   g("testdiv").innerHTML = "it works!";
   
  } does work. Maybe I'm confused about something else though?

Comment: @zjmiller I believe this works: `var g = document.getElementById.bind(document);` (However, `.bind()` is (as for now) implemented only in a couple of browsers, so you would want to use `underscore.js` or a similar library in order to implement this feature.)

Comment: @minitech [It does](http://jsfiddle.net/RNhNd/)?

Comment: @SimeVidas or recommend the [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

Comment: @Šime Vidas: He was talking about the assignment, not the invocation, so that's all I tried. Anwyays, I've now posted an answer (3 minutes too late).

Comment: @Raynos Oh yes, that one looks good `:)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that of *context*.  When you fire an object's function, it is fired with the object as the value of `this` (unless you specify otherwise).  `g = document.getElementById` puts the function `getElementById` into the variable `g`, but doesn't set the context.

Therefore, when you run `g(someId)`, there is no context on which the function can run.  It is run with the global object `window` as the value of `this`, and that doesn't work.  (To be precise, it doesn't work because you could be operating with any `document` object, not just `window.document`, and you haven't specified one.)

You **could** get around this with `call`, where you set the context:

```
g.call(document, someId);
```

However, this isn't an improvement over the original!

Comment: The biggest problem with using `call()` is that methods of host objects (such as `document`) are not guaranteed to be `Function` objects and may not therefore have a `call()` method. For example, `g.call(document, someId);` certainly won't work in IE < 8 and probably 8 also.

Comment: Why not use `bind` in the first place ?

Answer (score 3):

As [lonesomeday's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318724/1461424) already shows, the problem is with the execution context. I would like to add that there is a way to create a function with the execution context. Open your browser's Developer Tools for this page and try the following in the Console:

```
> document.getElementById('notify-container');
// <div id="notify-container"></div>

> var _d = document.getElementById;
// undefined

> _d
// ƒ getElementById() { [native code] }

> _d('notify-container');
// Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
//     at <anonymous>:1:1
```

As before, directly invoking the variable `_d` which is assigned to `document.getElementById` fails. But you can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind the execution context.

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```
> var d = document.getElementById.bind(document);
// undefined

> d('notify-container');
// <div id="notify-container"></div>
```

You also do not have to worry much about browser compatibility if you want to use `bind`: See https://caniuse.com/#feat=es5.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you call "g('somestr')" the "this" value is bound to the "window" and "document.getElementById" seens to expect to be bound to "document" instead "window"(makes sense to me =) ). Doing:

```
var g = document.getElementById;
g('somestr');
```

is like:

```
document.getElementById.call(window, 'somestr');
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the *context*. `document.getElementById(xxx)` runs in the context of `document`, but when you assign it to something, you get a TypeError because the context is probably `window`. See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/as3AQ/

So, you could use `call` or `apply`, but that's ugly. Just do the second way instead, or assign it to `document` and assign `document` to something if your objective is to minify your code.

Answer (score 1):

@minitech and @Tim Down
Thanks a lot for your feedback.

We have a lot of old code which worked like this

```
var $ = document.getElementById;
$("First");
```

It Failed with error message in modern browsers
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

All i did is replaced it as

```
var $ = function(x) { return document.getElementById(x); };
$("First");
```

Now we are back in the game :)