# How to set customer '$' function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document

In my code I use

```
$('button').hide();
```

To hide a button.

I do not want to include jQuery.
In the example below I try to define `$` as a `document.querySelector` function.

```
const $ = document.querySelector;
$('button').style.display = 'none';
```

I can't use `$` when binding the function this way.

Can you explain the reason why this is the case.

Also can you explain how I would be able to bind `$` to `document.querySelector`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I directly assign document.getElementById to a different function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318704/why-cant-i-directly-assign-document-getelementbyid-to-a-different-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example

```
const $ = document.querySelector;
```

We are binding the `querySelector` function to `$` With no document context this will fail since the `querySelector` function requires the parent document object to know what to query.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

You can get around this by including the document reference in your function.

```
const $ = selector => (document.querySelector(selector));
```

If you prefer more verbose code:

```
const $ = function(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
}
```

Or you can write this as:

```
function $(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
}
```

This post may be related to:

[Why can't I directly assign document.getElementById to a different function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318704/why-cant-i-directly-assign-document-getelementbyid-to-a-different-function)